# Engraving user input text on 3d model at run time in unity

Tags: unityscript, unity-game-engine

Is it possible to Engrave user input text on 3d model at runtime in unity? As shown in the picture below.  Since I am new to unity so please answer explicitly. Thankx in Advance. [Engraved text on a 3d ring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDv2o.png)

Answer (score 0):

Unity supports Blendshapes and Morph Targets on [meshes](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Mesh.html).  What you're asking to do is possible, but very complex and not something you could do easily as a beginner.

Comment: I have found Simple helvetica 3d character generator in Assets store.    https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/2925  ............ It generates 3d helvetica fonts for me. Only i need to do is take user input and set position or make colliders. Can you please help  in this way??? Thankx Sir.

Comment: What do you plan to do with the [input field](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-InputField.html)?  Do you have some sort of plan to use the 3D generator to "engrave" the user input?  Or are you just looking to generate 3D text based on the user input?

Comment: Well, i have to use it in my project. I am making a jewelry designing application to allow user to input any text and application should engrave text on ring (at runtime).  Is it clear or i should explain more?. Thankx for interest.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do, but I think you should try for yourself and ask a specific question when you run into an issue. Check out the link I posted in my last comment and try to get 3D text generated in your program by the user to start.